# How to use SimpleXml in PHP with files in AWS S3 buckets

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, simplexml

I have a routine that iterates through the elements of an XML using Xmliterator, loading it first with simplexml_load_file(). 
It works fine if it's in a specific folder of the web server but I'm struggling to understand how to read it directly from the S3 bucket.

Here's the code that reads from the web server folder location:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/' .     $_SESSION["username"] . "/" . $fnametp, 'SimpleXMLIterator');
```

Now if I want to read it directly from the S3 bucket (is that even a best practice?), what would the line look like? 
Here's what I tried to no avail:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($s3->getObjectUrl($config['s3']['bucket'], $fnametp), 'SimpleXMLIterator');
```

All S3 parameters are correct, I use these parameters elsewhere in my app and it's properly populating the bucket and reading from it. 
I'm most likely using the wrong method for what I'm trying to achieve but can't figure out how to navigate this. The error message is **403/forbiden**. I do have the proper rights and the file has been uploaded as public-read.

Thanks!

Comment: SOLUTION: There was a typo in the path to the S3 file (key). Simplexml actually works fine if you point it to a file in the S3 bucket using getObjectUrl.

Comment: I'm glad you found your solution. :) It is accepted practice here to add an Answer to your own question if you think it would help other readers in future. If you think the question and answer won't help, because it was just a typo, the tidy thing to do is delete the whole question. Either action saves it sitting around looking like it's still waiting for an answer.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll delete the question then because it was an honest mistake. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Can't delete the question, added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo in the path to the S3 file (key). Simplexml actually works fine if you point it to a file in the S3 bucket using getObjectUrl.